# Callback on $applyAsync?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if there was a way to define a callback method on an `$applyAsync` method call.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$scope.$applyAsync(function () {
    //do some stuff
}).then(function(){
    //do some more stuff
});
```

I'm not terribly versed in JS so maybe I'm just using the wrong function name

Comment: Why not just put `do some more stuff` in the same function that contains `do some stuff`?

Answer (score 0):

**At first:**
`$applyAsync` returns nothing (`undefined`), as a result, you can't call any method chaining after.

**At second:** `$applyAsync` can be used to queue up multiple expressions which need to be evaluated in the same digest. You should't use them to modify model, use `$apply` instead.

If you need to run some code asynchronously - just use $q service. Like so:

```
function async(){
   return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      //do some async stuff
      resolve('some result value')
   });
}

async().then(function(value){
   //do some more stuff after async function is resolved
})
```

If you need to immediately invoke `do some async stuff` without function declaration, use IIFE syntax:

```
some_async_stuff = (function($q){
   return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      //do some async stuff
      resolve('some result value')
   });
})($q).then(function(value){
    //value is 'some result value'
    //do some more stuff after async function is resolved
    return 'another result value'
})
```